# Select unique data from two different tables

Tags: php, mysql

i have two tables table1 and table2.

Table1 contains list of customer's (Cus_ID is unique here and its contains Emp_ID also)
Table2 contains list of employees (Emp_ID is unique here)

Every customer is created by some employee. Now i want to see which employee is managing which customer's in one query.

Comment: Sorry, it is unclear what you ask. What do you mean here by "distribute"? Try not to concentrate on technical terms, simply explain what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i am understanding you correctly you have customers that you want to assign to a specific operator.

you would need another column on the customer table, call the column user_id or something of the like.

You then check the operator is the one listed in that column for the customer.

This sql statement will do what you need.

```
$sql = "SELECT count(users.id) FROM users JOIN customers 
    WHERE users.id = customers.user_id 
        AND users.id = ' . $validated_operators_id . ' 
            AND customers.id = ' . $validated_customers_id  . '";
```